# In Python: Create a dictionary from a list of keys, but set all values to 0?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I've found elegant solutions to create dictionaries from two lists:

```
keys = [a, b, c]
values = [1, 2, 3]
list_dict = {k:v for k,v in zip(keys, values)}
```

But I haven't been able to write something for a list of keys with a single value (0) for each key. I've tried to do something like:

```
list_dict = {k:v for k,v in (zip(keys,[0 for i in range(keys)]))}
```

But it should be possible with syntax something simple like:

```
dict_totals = {k:v for k,v in zip(keys,range(0,3))}
```

I'm hoping for output that looks like {a:0, b:0, c:0}.
Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Note, `list_dict = {k:v for k,v in zip(keys, values)}` is an overly verbose way of writing `list_dict = dict(zip(keys, values))`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using `dict.fromkeys` alternate initialiser:

```
dict.fromkeys(keys, 0)
```

And offering you an easier way to do the first one:

```
dict(zip(keys, values))
```

Comment: …and, if you want to do it using dict comprehension anyway, it is just `list_dict = {k:0 for k in keys}` - nothing complicated about this…

Comment: The answer was "yes!" -- I was missing something obvious. Here's a link to the official docs for that function:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys